# How to deal with java to call object in its own declaration?

Tags: java, android, class, andengine

I have following problem:
I have class

```
public class HockeyActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity implements IOnSceneTouchListener, IOnAreaTouchListener {
```

and inside this class declaration:

```
final Player player= new Player( PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(   this.mPhysicsWorld, player.face, BodyType.DynamicBody,CIRCLE_FIXTURE_DEF));
```

here java yells that couldn't find `player.face`

and now declaration of Player class inside HockeyActivity class:

```
 class Player {
    final Body facebody;

final Sprite face = new Sprite(HockeyActivity.CAMERA_WIDTH / 2 + 200f,
    240, HockeyActivity.mFaceTextureRegion,
    getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
        final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

    switch (pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {
    case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        // Here 'body' refers to the Body object associated with
        // this sprite
        facebody.setTransform(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(),
            pSceneTouchEvent.getY(), facebody.getAngle());
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    return true;
    }
};

Player(Body f) {
    facebody = f;
}

}
```

how to deal without changing  final things?
Also I can't do it static because `getVertexBufferObjectManager()` is declared in HockeyActivity class:

```
    final VertexBufferObjectManager vertexBufferObjectManager = this.getVertexBufferObjectManager();
```

My another method dealing with problem:

```
final Sprite  face = new Sprite(CAMERA_WIDTH/2+200f, 240, this.mFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent, final float pTouchAreaLocalX, final float pTouchAreaLocalY) {

                                switch(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()){
                                    case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                        //Here 'body' refers to the Body object associated with this sprite
                                       facebody.setTransform(pSceneTouchEvent.getX(),     pSceneTouchEvent.getY(),                facebody.getAngle());
                                        break;
                                    default:
                                        break;
                                }
                                return true;    

}
```

//  few lines later:

```
final Body facebody = PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(  this.mPhysicsWorld, face, BodyType.KinematicBody,CIRCLE_FIXTURE_DEF);
        this.mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(face,facebody, true, true));
        facebody.setUserData("player1");
```

but the problem is inside `final Sprite face`, when Overriding method, because it doesn't see `facebody` declaration. how to make this Overriding method see facebody?

Comment: It should be Player.face instead of player.face and face needs to be static.

Comment: face cannot be static- when I change it to final static it yells that:
Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getVertexBufferObjectManager() from the type BaseGameActivity

Comment: try public static without final

Comment: hey Alex!
 
face cannot be static- when I change it to final static it yells that: Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getVertexBufferObjectManager() from the type BaseGameActivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something is not right on your code.
You want do instantiate an attribute "player", but using/passing the attribute itself as one of the parameters.
This can't be done (at least in java).

What you can do, **if** "face" is a constant, is:

- Declare FACE as a public static attribute
- On the instantiation, use a static reference to Player.FACE

Like this:

```
final Player player = new Player( PhysicsFactory.createCircleBody(   this.mPhysicsWorld, Player.FACE, BodyType.DynamicBody,CIRCLE_FIXTURE_DEF));
```

Otherwise, instead of passing player.face with the parameters on instantiation, try using a setter for it after player object is initialized.

Comment: I tried another way to do it- I rejected "class idea" and done it line after line. But another question on the way : ( - I wrote it in my main question post